# statements under if are not getting executed in robotframework(pythonselenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
${elementvisibity}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Enabled    ${loc_ddlRatePlan}           
        IF    ${elementvisibity} == 'True'
            Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${loc_ddlRatePlan}
```

variable status is been returned as true but wait statement inside if is not getting executed

should execute statements under if

Answer (score 1):

`Run Keyword And Return Status` keyword returns a boolean True or False. Your code makes a check against the string True or False. Here is the correct way:

```
Element Visibility
    ${elementvisibity}=   Run Keyword And Return Status    No Operation
    ${valueType}=         Evaluate    type(${elementvisibity})
    Log                   ${valueType}
    IF    ${elementvisibity} == ${TRUE}
            Log    True
    END
```